# .Net Serialization Exception error with .net 3.5 WCF application hosted in IIS with parallel extension System.Threading dll

Tags: .net, multithreading, wcf, serialization

I am getting following error when there is load on my .net 3.5 WCF application hosted in IIS with

An unhandled exception occurred and the process was terminated.

Application ID: DefaultDomain

Process ID: 9008

Exception: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException

Message: Unable to find assembly 'System.Threading, Version=1.0.2856.102, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

```
StackTrace:    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryAssemblyInfo.GetAssembly()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.GetType(BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, String name)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectMap..ctor(String objectName, String[] memberNames, BinaryTypeEnum[] binaryTypeEnumA, Object[] typeInformationA, Int32[] memberAssemIds, ObjectReader objectReader, Int32 objectId, BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, SizedArray assemIdToAssemblyTable)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryObjectWithMapTyped record)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSerializer.DeserializeObject(MemoryStream stm)
   at System.AppDomain.Deserialize(Byte[] blob)
   at System.AppDomain.UnmarshalObject(Byte[] blob)
```

Comment: does the assembly exist in the bin folder?

Comment: yes . application working fine until there is too much load

Comment: Are you using any DI? (Dependency injection)? Any other errors in the eventlog? seems like the AppPool has been unloaded at this point

Comment: No dependency injection

Comment: It was due to some unhnadled exception. Basically my application doing communication to another WCF service in a background thread. service request were getting timeout. So just have put try catch around the call

Answer (score 0):

It was due to some unhandled exception. Basically my application doing communication to another WCF service in a background thread. service request were getting timeout and throwing exception. So just have put try catch around the call. After that worker process stop crashing